# how to pass token as header authuriazation token in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a get API.
I am using Larvel passport for generating token

I want to pass generated token as header for the API.
How can I do that?

```
public function getalluser(User $user)
{
  
   
 $user = User::where('id', $user)->first();
 return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
 ]);    
}
}
```

[image]

Here even with out passing the authorization token I am getting some response if there is no token passed I want error and I want to pass token in order for this API to work

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show example code of your Api route

Comment: You need to have a request in order to access the CSRF token, you can request()->session()->token();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question - you want to get an authenticated user by token.

Follow installation instructions from Laravel docs - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#installation
Especially this part:

> Finally, in your application's config/auth.php
> configuration file, you should define an api authentication guard and
> set the driver option to passport. This will instruct your application
> to use Passport's TokenGuard when authenticating incoming API
> requests:
>
> ```php
> 'guards' => [
>     'web' => [
>         'driver' => 'session',
>         'provider' => 'users',
>     ],
>  
>     'api' => [
>         'driver' => 'passport',
>         'provider' => 'users',
>     ],
> ],
> ```

To authenticate users you should use the `api` guard.

Now you can create route to get current authenticated user - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#via-middleware

```php
Route::get('/user', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    // You will get authenticated user here
    $user = $request->user();
    dump($user);

    return new \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse(['id' => $user->id], 200);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

And here is about how pass authentication token to your app - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#passing-the-access-token
Just add `Authorization` header with this value `Bearer: <PUT_HERE_YOUR_TOKEN>`, replace <PUT_HERE_YOUR_TOKEN> with your issued token.

**UPD**:
If you want to get token used to authenticate user, you can look at `Passport` middleware source code - https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/11.x/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php

```php
if ($this->request->bearerToken()) {
    return $this->user = $this->authenticateViaBearerToken($this->request);
} elseif ($this->request->cookie(Passport::cookie())) {
    return $this->user = $this->authenticateViaCookie($this->request);
}
```

Comment: @Dmirty i tryed ur anwer i have added a screenshot of what i got when i tryed in postman

Comment: @meon try to add this header - Accept: application/json in Postman, then you should get 401 error with unauthenticated error message.

Comment: @meon and also you have wrong passed Authorization header in your screenshot, It should be: Authorization: Bearer <your token>, not Authorization: Bearer:<your_token>

Comment: yes i tryed without : still getiing same error @Dmitry

Comment: @meon your request should look like - https://imgur.com/a/F5aU2AH

Comment: @dymirty i got 401 when added like  that

Comment: @meon you are now getting correct error for unauthenticated user. To get 200 OK (successful response), issue new token, e.g. your new token is 12345, then your Authorization header should be - Bearer: 12345

Comment: but i dont generate new tokens. Every time when new users are registed their token are saved in database i dont what that to change every time

Comment: @meon you don't have to do it every time, but if token expires you need to issue new one. I ask you to issue new token just to be sure, that you are using not expired token.

Comment: here i  have a doubt in my databse inside oauth_access_tokens there is id and clinet_id  i was using client_id as token till now bu now i found out that client_id is same for all users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250574/discussion-between-meon-and-dmitry-k).